# URL mapping for a SharePoint Sub-Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, alternate-access-mapping

I have a web application running with a top root site. The URL mapping for this site is created and it is accessible as http://portal.bis.local/

Now I have created a sub-site under this site collection with the name "RMS". I want to configure a different URL mapping for this new sub-site as http://rms.bis.local

Is this feasible to configure? If yes then how? Because both sub-sites are now under same site collection?